# SQL server: update top(1) loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I've been looking over other entries and it looks like I'll need a cursor? I'm relatively new but I'm swinging high with this one. Any advice or help is welcome.

```
UPDATE top (1) dbo.table
SET [Status] = 1
WHERE [OrderId] = '1337' and [Status] = 0;
GO
```

If a record has an OrderID of 1337 and a status of 0, I want it to be changed to a 1, but this must be done one at a time.

**Edit**: I would like to make it loop until there are no [Status] = 0

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: What do you mean by one at a time?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you have a Primary key in your table.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to update records one by one?

Comment: @roughnex I do have a primary key that makes the record unique.The query works fine but I would like to make it into a loop that goes until there are no [Status] = 0

Comment: @SuperMarkio But why **must** this be done one row at a time?

Comment: @Lamak there is a separate process that has this limitation

Comment: @SuperMarkio - A broken update trigger?

Comment: Please elaborate on the "separate process".  You want to try and avoid RBAR (row by agonizing row) functionality.

Comment: You can add an [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?ppud=4) clause to an `UPDATE` statement.  If the problem can be resolved by providing the "separate process" with a list of updated rows, that may be the answer.

Answer (score 14):

```
WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
    UPDATE top (1) dbo.table
    SET [Status] = 1
    WHERE [OrderId] = '1337' and [Status] = 0

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK
    END
```

Comment: I guess my question is - how does it know where to get the Row count?

Comment: 'Loop Forever' with a condition to break out of the loop when no other rows are updated.

Comment: And this explains @@ROWCOUNT :)  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw my answer in the mix, too.  I use this in production systems where I need to make updates in small batches.  You can change the `select top 100 PKid` to `top 1` if you'd like to go in batches of one.  This method allows you to scale the batches of updates to something reasonable, finding a good compromise between minimal locks and set-based updates.  Obviously, this adds overhead over a single set-based statement, but the OP asked.

Note: I'm guessing there is a PK field on the table, and I just gave it an assumed name of `PKid`

```
declare @done bit = 0x0;
declare @inputs table (PKid int primary key)

while @done = 0x0
begin
    -- clear the temp table variable
    delete from @inputs

    -- build the small batch up updates into table variable
    insert into @inputs (PKid) 
    select top 100 PKid from dbo.table where [Status] = 0 and OrderId = '1337'

    -- if we inserted zero records, set our @done bit to 'true' so the while loop breaks
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        select @done = 0x1
    end

    -- make the update to the real table, constrained by the temp table variable
    update  t
    set     t.[Status] = 1
    from    dbo.table as t
    join    @inputs as i
    on      i.PKid = t.PKid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only one record with this sentence suggest you to do the following:

```
UPDATE dbo.table
SET [Status] = 1
WHERE rowId in (Select top(1) rowId from dbo.Table where [OrderId] = '1337' and Status = 0);
```

I don't know if you are using Transact or PL, so maybe you will need to change the rowId by ROW_NUMBER. You can change the rowId by a unique identifier also.
The Where clause will match the only row returned by the "select" clause.

You can do it with a cursor for update (like other answers) but if this a one time only taks, this is a quick solution.

Comment: Sometimes it can give you troubles depending on the SQL version (or flavor) that you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

Please avoid using a while or cursor loop to do this.

Here is a Update "Top"........work around:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/update-top-n-order-by-example/

```
/* START TSQL */

    if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Television]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
          BEGIN
                DROP TABLE [dbo].[Television]
          END
    GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Television] (
          TelevisionUUID [uniqueidentifier] not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() , 
          TelevisionName varchar(64) not null , 
          TelevisionKey int not null , 
          IsCheckedOut bit default 0
    )     
    GO


    ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Television_TelevisionUUID
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TelevisionUUID)
    GO


    ALTER TABLE dbo.Television ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Television_TelevisionName_UNIQUE 
    UNIQUE (TelevisionName)
    GO


    set nocount on

    declare @counter int
    select @counter = 11000
    declare @currentTVName varchar(24)
    declare @TopSize int
    select @TopSize = 10

    while @counter > 10000  /* this loop counter is ONLY here for fake data,….do not use this syntax for production code */
    begin

          select @currentTVName = 'TV:     '+ convert(varchar(24) , @counter)

          INSERT into dbo.Television ( TelevisionName , TelevisionKey ) values ( @currentTVName , @counter)

          select @counter = @counter - 1      
    end


    select count(*) as TV_Total_COUNT from dbo.Television 

    /*
    –Does not Work!
    Update TOP (10) dbo.Television
          Set IsCheckedOut = 1
    FROM
          dbo.Television tv
    ORDER BY tv.TelevisionKey
    */
    declare @AuditTrail table ( TelevisionUUID uniqueidentifier , OldIsCheckedOut bit , NewIsCheckedOut bit )

    ;
    WITH cte1 AS       
     (  SELECT 
          TOP (@TopSize) 

       TelevisionUUID , /* <<Note, the columns here must be available to the output */
       IsCheckedOut        
          FROM   
                dbo.Television tv      
        WITH ( UPDLOCK, READPAST , ROWLOCK ) /*  <<Optional Hints, but helps with concurrency issues   */
          WHERE  
                IsCheckedOut = 0              
          ORDER BY
                tv.TelevisionKey DESC        
    )
    UPDATE cte1
          SET  IsCheckedOut = 1
    output inserted.TelevisionUUID , deleted.IsCheckedOut , inserted.IsCheckedOut into @AuditTrail ( TelevisionUUID , OldIsCheckedOut , NewIsCheckedOut )
    ;
    print ''
    print 'Newly Checked Out Items'
    select * from dbo.Television tv where tv.IsCheckedOut <> 0

    print 'Output AuditTrail'
    select * from @AuditTrail
    print 'Not checked out items'
    select count(*) as TVCOUNTIsNOTCheckedOut from dbo.Television tv where tv.IsCheckedOut = 0
```

Comment: I don't see how is this supposed to update one row at a time for every row that meets the criteria

Comment: It is a generic example.......since UPDATE TOP does not exist.  Post you full DDL and DML and give expected results.....There should be a way to do an Update Top with a group by .. I believe.

Comment: The issue is that op wants to update one row at a time, in a process that updates every row that meet his criteria. So I don't think that he wants to execute this `TOP UPDATE` 100 times

Comment: And I'm suggesting that RBAR is a bad practice to put in, esp early on in his tsql career.  It would be better to show him how to get what he needs without RBAR.

Comment: I really like the top-voted answer because it's so simple and makes sense to me, but I understand what RBAR is now.

Comment: The answer is simple and straight forward.  But if you get into RBAR habits now, it's a bad situation.  I used to RBAR all the time......and nobody ever gave me good advice.  My advice: Always try to find a "set based" solution for problems.  I've written one cursor (or while loop) in 8 years since learning about set-based.

Comment: Thanks for the info granada. Good advice to hear while starting out.

Comment: Somebody didn't think so, they downvoted my response.  Sweet!

Comment: I think it's just not nooby friendly... it might take me a while to get to where I can interpret everything you wrote.